# ExceptionHandler stacktrace on Windows

Tags: windows-7, x86, windbg, dump

So, I see this line in one of the callstacks of a dump (x86/Windows 7) I am looking at. I have heavily snipped it as my question is pertaining only to this call.

```
Args to Child
01111111 04444444 05555555 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf
```

and going by: http://www.nynaeve.net/Code/KiUserExceptionDispatcher.c

It looks like the first two arguments on the stack must be the context record and the exception record. However with some experimentation I noted that `01111111` is not the first argument. It actually starts from `04444444`. So, in this case `.cxr 04444444` and `.exr 05555555` display sane output.

Now, I understand the debugger might just show whatever is on the stack at that point and I shouldn't probably rely on that alone but if everything **below** that line is marked with "stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong", how am I to know that I should ignore 01111111?

**UPDATE**

Lets try a different approach. Here are 2 relevant pieces of information:

```
Args to Child
0ccccccc 77895ac4 00000000 kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter+0x9e
[... various other calls here, leading up to ...]
0eeeeeee 0aaaaaaa 0bbbbbbb ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf
```

So, check this out. The lone parameter to `UnhandledExceptionFilter` is an EXCEPTION_POINTERS* structure, right?

```
0:010> dd 0ccccccc l2
0ddddddd  0bbbbbbb 0aaaaaaa
```

In the EXCEPTION_POINTERS struct, the first field is the EXCEPTION_RECORD (0bbbbbbb) while the second is the CONTEXT_RECORD (0aaaaaaa). However in the call to KiUserEceptionDispatcher, these arguments appear in the opposite way. Not to mention the fact 0eeeeeee is **NOT** the first parameter to KiUserExceptionDispatcher but 0ccccccc **IS** the first parameter to UnhandledExceptionFilter.

I am SO confused!

Comment: I'm not sure the prototype for `KiUserExceptionDispatcher` that you linked is correct. I believe it is actually `VOID KiUserExceptionDispatcher(PEXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord, PCONTEXT Context)`. In that case `01111111` is the exception record and `04444444` is the context record.

Comment: [This source](https://doar-e.github.io/blog/2013/10/12/having-a-look-at-the-windows-userkernel-exceptions-dispatcher/) and [this source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsvc/2012/10/08/making-sense-out-of-a-nonsensical-call-stack/) seem to back that up.

Comment: @SeanCline Well, the psuedo-code I linked to is from Ken Johnson, who is not only a Microsoftie but someone very well known in the windows internals world. Anyway, even if you swap these arguments, the issue here is 01111111 is *not* the first. The first argument starts from 04444444. That is the part I am trying to understand.

Comment: From when is that pseudo code? It doesn't have a date.

Comment: Would you mind posting a real WinDbg output? The `kb` command shows much more. Are you sure it's not a copy/paste issue? I also wonder about the `+0xf` offset. Ain't that too near the beginning of the method?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I lifted that psuedo-code from this blog post: http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=201. 10 years old :-) Also, I am dead sure its not a copy-paste error. I just checked again. Let me update with a bit more information. Unfortunately due to propreitory issues, I dare not post more than necessary.

Comment: really *KiUserExceptionDispatcher* have no *exactly* prototype for c/c++. feature ot this function - **he not have return address in stack**. the first pointer in stack (*[esp]* in x86 is point to *ExceptionRecord* and second pointer (*[esp+4]*) is point to *Context*

Comment: @RbMm Can you clarify? I don't quite understand your comment -- especially abou the return address being in the stack. What I really want to know is what `0eeeeeee` is in the callstack I posted on my update.

Comment: @ForeverLearning - usual function at `[esp]` (when first function instruction executed) have the return address - but `KiUserExceptionDispatcher` - have no return address in stack. in x86 - [esp] in x86 is point to ExceptionRecord and second pointer ([esp+4]) is point to Context

Comment: and you mistake about opposite way. can and say that `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` is **exactly** pointed by *esp* when `KiUserExceptionDispatcher` called

Comment: in [link](http://www.nynaeve.net/Code/KiUserExceptionDispatcher.c) - double error. at first nothing said about no return address, at second faster `(PEXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord, PCONTEXT ContextRecord)` in stack - in this order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**windows 7 x86 32 bit machine**
<kbd>winkey + r</kbd> -> windbg calc
bp ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
<kbd>f5</kbd>
divide 0/0 in calculator to raise an exception

```
(ac8.c8c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
Breakpoint 0 hit
eax=0023e1ec ebx=02b12fd0 ecx=00000003 edx=00000000 esi=02b13178 edi=00000001
eip=76e77048 esp=0023dee0 ebp=0023e23c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000202
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher:
76e77048 fc              cld
```

your post shows the return address to be + 0xf so lets see whats upto that point

```
0:000> u . .+f
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher:
76e77048 fc              cld
76e77049 8b4c2404        mov     ecx,dword ptr [esp+4]
76e7704d 8b1c24          mov     ebx,dword ptr [esp]
76e77050 51              push    ecx
76e77051 53              push    ebx
76e77052 e85d88fdff      call    ntdll!RtlDispatchException (76e4f8b4)
76e77057 0ac0            or      al,al
```

so it appears you have broken after entering RtlDispatchException from your call stack

breaking to enter the call

```
0:000> tc
eax=0023e1ec ebx=0023dee8 ecx=0023df08 edx=00000000 esi=02b13178 edi=00000001
eip=76e77052 esp=0023ded8 ebp=0023e23c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000202
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xa:
76e77052 e85d88fdff      call    ntdll!RtlDispatchException (76e4f8b4)


0:000> t
eax=0023e1ec ebx=0023dee8 ecx=0023df08 edx=00000000 esi=02b13178 edi=00000001
eip=76e4f8b4 esp=0023ded4 ebp=0023e23c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000202
ntdll!RtlDispatchException:
76e4f8b4 8bff            mov     edi,edi
```

looking at stack if you ask windbg to be verbose it will even decipher the context for you

```
0:000> kb 3
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0023ded0 76e77057 0023dee8 0023df08 0023dee8 ntdll!RtlDispatchException
01 0023ded0 7521b760 0023dee8 0023df08 0023dee8 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf
02 0023e23c 7579359c e06d7363 00000001 00000003 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58
0:000> kv 3
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0023ded0 76e77057 0023dee8 0023df08 0023dee8 ntdll!RtlDispatchException (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
01 0023ded0 7521b760 0023dee8 0023df08 0023dee8 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf (FPO: [2,0,0]) (CONTEXT @ 0023df08)
02 0023e23c 7579359c e06d7363 00000001 00000003 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
```

exr output

```
0:000> .exr poi(@esp+4)
ExceptionAddress: 7521b760 (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x00000058)
   ExceptionCode: e06d7363 (C++ EH exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 3
   Parameter[0]: 19930520
   Parameter[1]: 0023e294
   Parameter[2]: 007c15b4
unable to find C-Runtime symbols, even with unqualified search
```

context record output

```
0:000> dt ntdll!_CONTEXT poi(@esp+8)
   +0x000 ContextFlags     : 0x1003f
   +0x004 Dr0              : 0
   +0x008 Dr1              : 0
   +0x00c Dr2              : 0
   +0x010 Dr3              : 0
   +0x014 Dr6              : 0
   +0x018 Dr7              : 0
   +0x01c FloatSave        : _FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
   +0x08c SegGs            : 0
   +0x090 SegFs            : 0x3b
   +0x094 SegEs            : 0x23
   +0x098 SegDs            : 0x23
   +0x09c Edi              : 1
   +0x0a0 Esi              : 0x2b13178
   +0x0a4 Ebx              : 0x2b12fd0
   +0x0a8 Edx              : 0
   +0x0ac Ecx              : 3
   +0x0b0 Eax              : 0x23e1ec
   +0x0b4 Ebp              : 0x23e23c
   +0x0b8 Eip              : 0x7521b760
   +0x0bc SegCs            : 0x1b
   +0x0c0 EFlags           : 0x202
   +0x0c4 Esp              : 0x23e1ec
   +0x0c8 SegSs            : 0x23
   +0x0cc ExtendedRegisters : [512]  "???"
```

you can even get both by use .extptr (note you may need to reset context to default scope using .cxr after using this command)

```
0:000> .exptr (@esp+4)

----- Exception record at 0023dee8:
ExceptionAddress: 7521b760 (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x00000058)
   ExceptionCode: e06d7363 (C++ EH exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 3
   Parameter[0]: 19930520
   Parameter[1]: 0023e294
   Parameter[2]: 007c15b4
unable to find C-Runtime symbols, even with unqualified search

----- Context record at 0023df08:
eax=0023e1ec ebx=02b12fd0 ecx=00000003 edx=00000000 esi=02b13178 edi=00000001
eip=7521b760 esp=0023e1ec ebp=0023e23c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000202
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58:
7521b760 c9              leave


0:000> kb 3
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0023e23c 7579359c e06d7363 00000001 00000003 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58
01 0023e274 0079eee0 0023e294 007c15b4 02b13178 msvcrt!_CxxThrowException+0x48
02 0023e288 0079146e 02b13178 80000002 c87a3f02 calc!divrat+0x69

0:000> .cxr
Resetting default scope

0:000> kb 3
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0023ded0 76e77057 0023dee8 0023df08 0023dee8 ntdll!RtlDispatchException
01 0023ded0 7521b760 0023dee8 0023df08 0023dee8 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf
02 0023e23c 7579359c e06d7363 00000001 00000003 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58
```

hope this suffices to research on your own for your specific situation for which you cant divulge the actual windbg stack trace

Comment: blabb (you should really change your name :-)): thanks a ton for this! I was doing similar experimentation to understand this better but I like your short cuts (poi(@esp+4)). Thanks once again!